# Parameter is not valid. when trying to open a particular jpg image as a bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

I am opening an image into stream and trying to initialise a bitmap object from it.  However, I am getting a rather uninformative "parameter is not valid." exception.

This is the code:

```
using (var webClient = new Classes.WebClient())
    using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead(filePath))
        using (var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
        {
            if (tempBitmap.Width > 500)
                logoBitmap = CustomImageProcessor.ResizeToWidth(tempBitmap);
            else
                logoBitmap = new Bitmap(tempBitmap);
        }
```

this is the image (daft image but we are t-shirt printing company): https://cdn.insyncsoftware.co.uk/Uploads/6A9E190E-52AB-4749-B5A8-7B43DEF10119/MasterDesigns/56962/RDT_20230224_0134133530323197128594639.jpg

and this is the exception and stack trace:

Message: Parameter is not valid.

Stack Trace: at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream) at LaunchPad3_1.Visual.Visual2.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0(ViewPoint viewPoint) in C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\LaunchPad3_1\LaunchPad3_1\Visual\Visual2.cs:line 311

Comment: I'm guessing that the data is not a valid `Bitmap`. If you save the data from the stream to a file, can you open it in an image app?

Comment: won't open in photoshop but will open in ms paint.  What's that about?

Comment: have the same problem with this image:

https://cdn.insyncsoftware.co.uk/Uploads/6A9E190E-52AB-4749-B5A8-7B43DEF10119/MasterDesigns/60220/IMG_20220426_202956_189.jpg